# Create Unique Index in Objectbox

Tags: objectbox

Is there any way to create an unique index on an entity field?

There is an Index annotation but there is no field to set. In the decompiled code is a unique field that has been commented out.

So do I have to perform the uniqueness check myself before saving the entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a upcoming feature tracked [here](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/20).